# Is it possible to add Github releases link to Ubuntu sources.list?

Tags: ubuntu, github, repository, apt, ubuntu-18.04

I actually reinstall my Ubuntu, and I need plenty of programs. Of course I want to use it in the newest versions. However, Ubuntu official repositories often include older versions of programs. So I need to download the newest versions manually, e.g. from Github.

Is it possible to add entry to Ubuntu `/etc/apt/sources.list` that make possible to download and automatically update programs from Github releases?

Something like:

`deb https://github.com/git/git/releases`

Any help will be apreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is directly possible, because I just found this:

- https://github.com/rpatterson/github-apt-repos

> The github-apt-repos utility currently does roughly the following:
>
> 1. Download the *.deb files from the latest GitHub release for a git checkout from GitHub
> 2. Make an APT repository from the released *.deb files
> 3. Upload the APT repository to a special GitHub release which Debian/Ubuntu users can use to keep up-to-date.

... but it's supposed to run on a *server*, so it is not something you'd do on your PC (unless you set up an APT repository server on your PC, and go with that trouble).